# How do I delete an AppEngine Version, Service or App using Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api

I see [this documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/googleapis/java/all/latest/apidocs/com/google/appengine/v1/DeleteServiceRequest.Builder.html) of the REST wrappers for deleting an AppEngine  service (and likewise a version). But how does one use them? I don't see any code samples, and since these REST wrappers are auto-generated, the usage is not intuitive.

Are there code samples of how to delete an AppEngine version or service

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a version:

```java
    import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
    import com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter;
    import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;

    import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
    import com.google.api.services.appengine.v1.Appengine;
    import com.google.api.services.appengine.v1.model.Operation;


    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();

    HttpRequestInitializer requestInitializer = new HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials);
    Appengine engine = new Appengine.Builder(
            GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), requestInitializer
    ).setApplicationName("application").build();
    // Replace to delete service, see below.
    Appengine.Apps.Services.Versions versions = engine.apps().services().versions();
    Appengine.Apps.Services.Versions.Delete del = versions.delete(project, service, version);
    Operation result = del.execute();
```

To delete a service replace the 2d- and 3rd-to-last lines above with this:

```
Appengine.Apps.Services services = engine.apps().services();
Appengine.Apps.Services.Delete del =   services.delete(project, service);
```

Deleting an App is not possible as an AppEngine app is on the project level. (Historically, projects were originally AppEngine apps.)

JavaDocs for the Delete API can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/appengine/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/appengine/v1/Appengine.Apps.Services.Versions.Delete.html), though without usage examples.

Another approach does not use the GCP API at all, but rather wraps the gcloud command line tool. See [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/blob/8038f8216a1410f67627dad91f86d61fd67b6c51/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/tools/maven/it/AbstractMojoIntegrationTest.java#L44).